# How can I pass my dropdown style value on to my php file via jQuery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here's the markup for my dropdown:

```
    <select id="themes">
        <option selected="selected">Themes:</option>
        <option value="default">Default</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="bw">Black and White</option>
        <option value="invert">Invert</option>
    </select>
```

And the jQuery I'm using right now:

```
$("#themes").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "css/style.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {"theme="+$(this).val(); }
    })
});
```

This gives me a console error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +". All I'm trying to do is pass $_GET['theme'] on to my style.php so I can process it with conditionals. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Create data as an object, you have syntax issues in your code

```
$("#themes").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "css/style.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            theme: $(this).val()
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your code. You need to provide key value pair while creating an object in JavaScript [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```
$("#themes").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "css/style.php",
       method: "GET",
       data: {
         theme: $(this).val()
       }
    });
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhfoj6me/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggesting that fix. However, I still receive the same JS console error, and my !empty check in my php file still shows $_GET['theme'] isn't being set. Any ideas?

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle. there is no problem on client side. clear php cache...

Comment: Really strange, but still not working. This is the css/style.php file: http://pastebin.com/42yBgrSW

Answer (score 0):

do it like this.............

```
    $("#themes").change(function(){

    var theme = $(this).val();


    $.ajax({

                 url: "css/style.php",
                  method: "GET",
                data: {theme : theme },                                                                                                     
                success:  function(data) {



                    }//end of success
            });

        });
```

i always used this technique   then fetch it using

```
   $theme = $_GET['theme'];
```

Comment: please check again i mistakenly add s at theme please check it again

Comment: Strangely, this still isn't working for me. Here's my implementation in style.php: http://pastebin.com/42yBgrSW

The background of the page is still set to black when I navigate to it in my browser, and I got an undefined index error for $_GET['theme'] when I tried to echo it.

And my code, directly from the JS file:
http://pastebin.com/TT2kMHuL